# Get text from text field of type email?

Tags: c#, watin

So I am trying to read a site with C#. I have it so it opens a website and goes to read a TextField. However the website has the text field like so.

```
<input name="loginMail" class="c-txtfld c-txtfld-fixed c-txtfld-green c-txtfld-medium" id="login-email" type="email" placeholder="Email address" pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*">
```

And because of this I can get C# to read it.

```
TextField emailaddressfield = this.Document.TextField(Find.BySelector("form#login-form.credential-form input#login-email")
```

It will work however if I edit the `type` attribute to `text`.

I want to keep this as `email`. How can I read it like that?

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: He can not get the `value` of textfield with its `type='email'`

Comment: @Shaharyar the question reads quite the opposite, or there are some negations missing

Comment: As I understood the problem, he can get the value of textfield with its type=text, but can not get with the type=email. That's what he wants as I got the question.

Comment: @Shaharyar You are correct, I cannot read the value of type='email' but I can read it whilst type='text' however I would like to see how I can read it whilst type='email'

Comment: is this using Watin?

Comment: @Joe Yes, I have looked on the net and some people say that this needs to be handled by the website on ASP.net. However I do not have access to the website in question and cannot simply edit the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create a custom control from existing WatiN controls (HTML). In order to get text field value of type `email`, we need to create a custom control which would be of type TextField. Please try below code.

```
[ElementTag("input", InputType = "email", Index = 5)]    
public class EmailTextField : Element<EmailTextField>
{
    public EmailTextField(DomContainer domContainer, ElementFinder finder): base(domContainer, finder)
    { }
    public EmailTextField(DomContainer domContainer, INativeElement element): base(domContainer, element)
    { }
}

EmailTextField emailaddressfield = this.Document.EmailTextField(Find.BySelector("form#login-form.credential-form input#login-email")
```

(Pseudo code - not complied)