# How do I get a handle on a datalist to access it options

Tags: html, user-interface, testing, watin, datalist

I am writing a UI test and have been using WatiN.core which gives access to buttons, divs and TextFields. However it does not give me access to a datalist. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataList` is HTML 5 tag, which was introduced after WatiN was released. But with WatiN's ability, we can create the new HTML controls/tags with ease. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445816/get-text-from-text-field-of-type-email) post for better view. Do let me know if this doesn't work.